# Laravel: How to save images to public folder?

Tags: laravel, upload

I am having trouble uploading a user image to my public folder. The file name generates correctly, and saves the name to my database, except the iamge itself refuses to get saved into my public folder. What am I doing wrong?

```
  public function update_avatar(Request $request) {
  if($request->hasFile('avatar')) {

    $avatar = $request->file('avatar');
    $filename = time() . "." . $avatar->getClientOriginalExtension();

    Image::make($avatar)->resize(300,300)->save(public_path('/uploads/'.$filename)); ==> This is causing me errors

    user = Auth::user();
    $user->avatar = $filename;
    $user->save();

  }
```

Comment: Does this help at all? https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/image-upload-using-storage-function-to-public-folder?page=1

Comment: What does public_path('/ uploads ...) return? What is the path it tries to save to?

Comment: which error are you get? please describe your error.
So i will help you

Answer (score 1):

> The public disk is intended for files that are going to be publicly accessible. By default, the `public` disk uses the local driver and stores these files in `storage/app/public`. To make them accessible from the web, you should create a symbolic link from `public/storage` to  `storage/app/public`. This convention will keep your publicly accessible files in one directory that can be easily shared across deployments.
>
> To create the symbolic link, you may use the `storage:link` Artisan command:

```
php artisan storage:link
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/filesystem

Answer (score 1):

I think you should try this:

```
$destinationPath = public_path('uploads');

Image::make($avatar)->resize(300,300)->save($destinationPath.'/'.$filename);
```

Answer (score 0):

First you must move your image to destination directory and then resize it.

```
$avatar->move(public_path('/uploads/'.$filename));
Image::make(public_path('/uploads/'.$filename))->resize(300,300)->save(public_path('/uploads/'.$filename));
```

**Note**

Check the directory that you moving your file there is already exist.

Comment: When I do this, it does not move the image correctly: I end up getting a folder with the image name (sakjdha.jpg), and then a jibberish document within it (ASCII), and the result (1/1) NotReadableException
Unable to find file ().